# Help with date conditionals

Tags: conditionals, date

Need help to get this to work:

```
{if {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="November 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="January 7th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
6 Jan

{if:elseif {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="January 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="February 21st, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
20 Feb

{if:elseif {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="February 20th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="March 28th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
27 Mar

{if:elseif {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="March 27th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="May 16th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
15 May

{if:elseif {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="May 15th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="August 4th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
3 Aug

{if:elseif {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="August 3rd, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="September 12th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
11 Sept

{if:elseif {current_time} >= {exp:str_to_time date="September 11th, {current_time format='%Y'}"} && {current_time} <= {exp:str_to_time date="November 7th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}}
6 Nov
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to quote all of your plugin-generated variables inside your conditionals and remove the braces from `current_time`.

Also, I don't think you need all the `elseif` conditions - you should be able to do this with a series of `if` statements since they are all mutually-exclusive - that will read a little cleaner.

```
{if current_time >= '{exp:str_to_time date="November 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}' 
    && current_time <= '{exp:str_to_time date="January 7th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}'}
        6 Jan
{/if}

{if current_time >= '{exp:str_to_time date="January 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}' 
    && current_time <= '{exp:str_to_time date="February 21st, {current_time format='%Y'}"}'}
        20 Feb
{/if}
```

Etc.

Comment: Hi Derek, Thanks for reply but it doesn't work Im afraid. I need to be able to show for example 6th Jan if the current date is more than 6th Nov (Last year) and less than 7th Jan (current year)

Comment: I think I solved the problem with the (previous year) months by write the code like so: `{if current_time >= '{exp:str_to_time date="November 5th, {current_time format='%y'} -1 year"}'`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the format you are comparing against.

For example 'current_time' will look like

```
1454583625
```

so you need to make sure that

```
{exp:str_to_time date="November 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}"}
```

is outputting a number comparable to that

also sometimes I find wrapping my variables in quotes makes them work when they otherwise wouldn't

```
{if "{current_time}" >= "{exp:str_to_time date='November 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}'}" && "{current_time}" <= "{exp:str_to_time date='January 7th, {current_time format="%Y"}'}"}
```

you may also need to bracket your if statmnt

```
{if ("{current_time}" >= "{exp:str_to_time date='November 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}'}") && ("{current_time}" <= "{exp:str_to_time date='January 7th, {current_time format="%Y"}'}")}
```

also try

```
 {if ("{current_time}" >= "{exp:str_to_time date='November 6th, {current_time format='%Y'}'}") AND ("{current_time}" <= "{exp:str_to_time date='January 7th, {current_time format="%Y"}'}")}
```

but also conditions can be a little finicky with variables inside them so there is a plugin I use called [ifElse on devotee](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse)

you may also find [switchee](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) helpful as it takes conditionals case by case, istead of checking EVERY if statment.

**BUT** also if your date is 'hardcoded' anyway could you not just make a timestring of that?

```
{if "{current_time format="%y%m%d"}" >= "{current_time format="%y"}1106"}
```

**Edit Edit**
dammit this thread is soo old! why does stack exchange do that - put old threads to the top?